# Paypal buy now button takes to sandbox account login page

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using Paypal buy now button on my website. For testing purpose I am using paypal sandbox account. The problem is when I click on buy now button, it takes me to sandbox sign in page when I have not already signed in. The following is my buy now button code

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="skariz_1316503728_biz@gmail.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="PSYC">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="2.00">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
        <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="test@test.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
        <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
        <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the sandbox account buttons require you to log into your sandbox account to use it. If memory serves the last time I was working with an IPN I had to do that. There may also be a section where you create test customer sandbox accounts, but I can't recall.

Comment: Yes, that's https://developer.paypal.com/
To summarize what Eonasdan said; you simply need to be signed in to https://developer.paypal.com/ whenever you try to access anything on https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/